# HTML/CSS - Transition Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have a setup like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_01"></div>
  <div id="inner_02"></div>
  <div id="inner_03"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to build a transition with the following properties:

1. When hovering over `inner_01` the `background-color` of `inner_02` and `inner_03` should change.
2. When hovering over `inner_02` the `background-color` of `inner_01` and `inner_03` should change.
3. When hovering over `inner_03` the `background-color` of `inner_01` and `inner_02` should change.

This is my current approach:

- **Hover over `inner_01`**:

  ```
  #wrapper #inner_01:hover ~ #inner_02 {
    /* Transition *
    transition: background 5s;

    /* Color */
    background: #ffee00;
  }

  /* Don't know how to effect inner_03 */
  ```
- **Hover over `inner_02`**:

  ```
  #wrapper #inner_02:hover ~ #inner_03 {
    /* Transition *
    transition: background 5s;

    /* Color */
    background: #ffee00;
  }

  /* Don't know how to effect inner_01 */
  ```
- **Hover over `inner_03`**:

  ```
  /* Don't know how to effect inner_01/inner_02 */
  ```

I think I'm missing some kind of CSS-selector...
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Those CSS selectors don't exist yet. Maybe in the future. Right now, you can only affect things that come after other things. A workaround would be to use JavaScript to assign and remove classes.

Comment: @MrLister Oh, that's pretty sad, but I'm happy for your quick answer. If you'd like to post a short answer (maybe with a minimal JavaScript hint) I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing it out, this would require something like this in JavaScript (without any libraries).

```js
document.getElementById('inner_02').addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {   
  document.getElementById('inner_01').classList.add('newbkgnd');
});

document.getElementById('inner_02').addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {   
  document.getElementById('inner_01').classList.remove('newbkgnd');
});

document.getElementById('inner_03').addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {   
  document.getElementById('inner_01').classList.add('newbkgnd');
  document.getElementById('inner_02').classList.add('newbkgnd');
});

document.getElementById('inner_03').addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {   
  document.getElementById('inner_01').classList.remove('newbkgnd');
  document.getElementById('inner_02').classList.remove('newbkgnd');
});
```

```css
/* make the divs visible initially. Just for debugging purposes */
#wrapper > div {
 width: 20em; height: 2em;
 margin:.5em 0;
  border:1px solid;
  /* Transition */
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#inner_01:hover ~ #inner_02,
#inner_01:hover ~ #inner_03,
#inner_02:hover ~ #inner_03,
.newbkgnd {
  /* Color */
  background-color: #ffee00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_01"></div>
  <div id="inner_02"></div>
  <div id="inner_03"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: or, of course, based on @nicael's answer, this much simpler CSS-only solution...

```css
/* make the divs visible initially. Just for debugging purposes */
#wrapper > div {
 width: 20em; height: 2em;
 margin:.5em 0;
  border:1px solid;
  /* Transition */
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#wrapper:hover > div {
  /* Color */
  background-color: #ffee00;
}
#wrapper:hover > div:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_01"></div>
  <div id="inner_02"></div>
  <div id="inner_03"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the color of all the `inner_*` divs and then change back to black the color of hovered `inner_*` div.

```css
#wrapper:hover{
  color:red;
}
[id^=inner]:hover{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_01">test1</div>
  <div id="inner_02">test2</div>
  <div id="inner_03">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Way better than a JavaScript based solution. I had to make some modifications to your method to make it satisfactory to the OP though.

Comment: @MrLister You mean transitions? As you've already mentioned them in your answer, there's a dilemma. Could I edit my answer to include transitions, i.e. `[id^=inner]{transition:color 1s;}`?

Comment: Actually I meant the specificity of the colors. You change all of #wrapper, while the OP was concerned only about changing the three named divs inside. Oh, and background color rather than color.

Comment: @MrLister Ok, let it be this way :) Just a small notice: in your case you are targeting all the inner divs, not just `inner*` ;)